# How can I prevent Siri from using my nickname?

Tags: iphone, siri, ios

I've given myself a nickname of "Me" so that I can tell Siri to "email me." Unfortunately, Siri now uses this nickname all the time, thus producing nonsense like "It's 8:25 PM. Good evening, me" when I ask what time it is.

Ideally, Siri wouldn't use my name at all, but failing that, how can I tell it to use my first name instead of my nickname when it insists on addressing me by name? I still want to be able to say things like "email me" or "text me".

I'm using iOS 11 on an iPhone 6.

Comment: Check this out https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/248157/265046

Comment: I saw that thread, but I'm pretty sure that if you do that, things like "email me" won't work.